# iOS5 CSS. position fixed becomes useless with pinch zoom

Tags: css, webkit, ios5

The CSS property position:fixed has is not functional with iOS5. However when the user pinch zooms on iOS5 or MAC OSX lion the header becomes unusable as it modifies it's sized to adjust and compensate in a manner that tends to move the content in question off screen.

What we need is a means that prevents the fixed element from zooming whilst allowing the other content to zoom. Is this possible?

Comment: Is this question about iOS and pinch zoom particularly, or would you like a general solution including desktop browsers?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a full-screen wrapper that contains your header, then set `meta` tags to disable scaling for the page. The content want to zoom like normal would then need to exist inside that wrapper, and have scripts that respond to touch events. [Guide to get you started . . .](http://matt.might.net/articles/how-to-native-iphone-ipad-apps-in-javascript/)

Comment: There's gotta be a better way to do this. This does not let us pan/zoom using the builtin pan/zoom that is smooth and suspends JS execution.